# Сделать боковую картинку с псевдоэлементами

Tags: html, css, изображения

https://prnt.sc/rckqmg

Как сделать css и html такую штуку ? Я что то застрял.

html

```
<div class="div">
<img src="circle.png" alt="" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;">
</div>
```

css

```
.div::before{
    content: url("circle_two.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

div img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

div:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: -15px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 170px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #153c5f;
  border-radius: 80% 100% 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 35% 90%, 55% 98%, 55% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://quintalk.com/application/files/7515/5006/6802/129.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle__img,
.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle__img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 35px solid #00f;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img class="circle__img" src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.div::before{
      content: '';
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 60px;
      top: 10px;
      left: -10px;
   }
```